# Noether Normalisation Theorem of my book

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Lemma 2.4.11 of [1] that I'm self-studying, they state the Noether Normalisation Theorem as follows;

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be an algebraic set, and let $K[X] = K[y_1, \dots, y_n]$ be its coordinate ring. Then there exist $m \leq n$ linear forms $L_1, \dots L_m$ in $y_1, \dots y_n$ such that 
> (1) $L_1, \dots L_m$ are algebraically independent over $K$; 
> (2) there exist a linear combination $L_{m+1}$ of the $y_i$ with coefficients in $K[L_1, \dots, L_m]$ such that $K(X) \simeq K(L_1, \dots, L_m, L_{m+1})$.

The theorem I've read before was in the following form;

> For any field $k$, and any finitely generated commutative $k$-algebra $A$, there exists a non-negative integer $d$ and algebraically independent elements $y_1,y_2,\dots,y_d\in A$ such that $A$ is a finitely generated module over the polynomial ring $k[y_1,y_2,\dots,y_d]$.

How (2) of mine corresponds to that familiar form of the theorem??

### Reference

[1] Lectures on Curves, Surfaces and Projective Varieties, A Classical View of Algebraic Geometry, by Beltrametti et al.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I see! That makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A $k$-algebra $A$ has a basis: $y_1,...,y_n$. Hence $A = k[y_1,...,y_n]$.

Now both the theorems say there exists algebraically independent elements which is a linear combination of $y_1,...,y_n$ with $m = d$ with $L_i$ in theorem 1 $= y_i$ in theorem 2, $1 \leq i \leq d$ with the differences being that:
In Theorem 2 it says, $A$ is a finitely generated module over $k[L_1,...,L_d]$.
In theorem 1, it says, $A$ is generated by $1,L_{d+1},L_{d+1}^2,...,$

Choose $m = d$ to be maximal number of algebraically independent elements in $A$, Now any other element is algebraic over $k[L_1,...,L_d]$. To show the equivalence of Theorem 1 and Theorem 2, we need some kind of primitive element theorem for $k$-algebras to show that the finitely generated module mentioned in Theorem 2, is actually generated by $1,L_{d+1},L_{d+1}^2,...$. An example of such a theorem : [https://www.math.uh.edu/~hjm/pdf25(4)/1DOBBS.pdf](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Ehjm/pdf25(4)/1DOBBS.pdf)
.

The other difference is $y_1,...,y_n$ is an algebraic set in Theorem 1 whereas no such restriction is present in Theorem 2. This is something i believe is specific w.r.t context of the theorem.

Comment: I just assumed basis to be $y_1, ... ,y_n$ and took $L_i$ to be linear combination. Its just notational issue you r talking about. In theorem 2, i could use $z_1,...,z_n$ as basis of $k$-algebra $A$ and $y_1,....,y_d$ as linear combination of basis. Its just notational issue. Notation got changed between Theorem 1 and Theorem 2. In theorem 1, $y_1,..y_n$ is algebraic basis and $L_1,..L_d$ is the linear combination. In theorem 2, basis is unspecified and $y_1,..,y_d$ is the linear combination of basis.

Comment: @Balajisb Thank you for your answer! I understood that The first version has more information than the second one, and although (2) of theorem1 is missing in 2 somehow (e.g., primitive element theorem you mentioned) can be obtained with an effort! I think I'm good to go at the moment! Thank you!